# ¿Se puede en tkinter cambiar el texto de una label al pulsar un botón, para que el nuevo texto sean los elementos de una lista en distintas filas?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, label, texto

Me gustaría que al pulsar un botón en tkinter, cambiase el texto que muestra una label y el nuevo texto sean los elementos de una lista pero con un salto de línea entre ellos. Como esto pero que funcione, porque los métodos que se usan con print no me funcionan aquí, lo he intentado metiendo los saltos entre los elementos de la lista y también intentando meterlos en un bucle en la función activada con el botón, con "end", etc y no me funciona y no he encontrado formas particulares de tkinter para hacerlo.

```
    from tkinter import *
    raiz=Tk()
    frame=Frame(raiz)
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    etiqueta=Label (frame, text='', font= ("",25) )
    etiqueta.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    boton=Button(frame, background="red", command=lambda:imprimir(), text="Pulsa", font= ("",25) )
    boton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    a=[1,2,3,4]
    for i in a:
        i=i,'\n'

    def imprimir():
        etiqueta['text']=a

    raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema tiene poca relación con Tkinter.

#### Introducción al método join

Lo que estás buscando es el método [str.join](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) de las cadenas. El método str.join recibe un argumento que sería un iterable (lista, tupla, generador, etc) y une cada item de dicho iterable usando de separador a str.

Por ejemplo:

```
"-".join(("hola", "mundo", "marciano"))
```

Genera:

```
hola-mundo-marciano
```

Pero hay un problema. str.join necesita que todos los items del iterable sean cadenas. Por lo que previamente habrá que convertir cada item en cadenas. Para esto lo más util es la comprensión de generador. Este tutorial sobre el tema es muy bueno, te recomiendo leerlo: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones

#### Solución

Usa comprensión de generador junto al método join:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a = "\n".join(str(x) for x in a)
print(a)
```

Produce:

```
1
2
3
4
```

El resto de tu código está bien e implementando mi propuesta debería de funcionarte como esperas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Lo había solucionado usando Listbox en lugar de label, pero ciertamente funcionó el método join.